# Unit testing method that uses IMemoryCache extension method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to write a unit test using MSTest and Moq for a method that uses an extension method of IMemoryCache. Situation:

```
public class ClassToTest
{        
  private IMemoryCache Cache { get; }

  public ClassToTest(IMemoryCache cache)
  {          
    Cache = cache;
  }

  public async Task<SomeType> MethodToTest(string key)
  {
    // Get is an extension method defined in Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory
    var ci = Cache.Get<CachedItem<T>>(key);

    // Do stuff with cached item
  }
}
```

How can I unit test this?

So far i tried:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethodToTest()
{
  IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
  services.AddMemoryCache();

  var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
  var memoryCache = serviceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();

  ClassToTest testClass = new ClassToTest(memoryCache);
}
```

This gives me the following error: "'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddMemoryCache' and no accessible extension method 'AddMemoryCache' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

Does anyone know how to unit test this method? Preferably without changing the method itself.
Is there a standard way to do this?
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the necessary references to have access to that extension method? Are you missing a `using` directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to modify `ClassToTest`. You can have a property of type `Func<string, CachedItem<T>>` that gets assigned to use the extension in your class' constructor:

```
public Func<string, CachedItem<T>> GetFromCache { get; set; }
public ClassToTest(IMemoryCache cache)
{          
    Cache = cache;
    GetFromCache = key => Cache.Get<CachedItem<T>>(key);
}
```

Then, when you want to test that class, you can override that behaviour by saying:

```
ClassToTest testClass = new ClassToTest(memoryCache);
testClass.GetFromCache = key => /* something else */;
```

Generally speaking, extension methods are still just syntactic sugar over static methods, so using them like `ClassToTest` does will introduce dependencies and make code harder to test in isolation.

Comment: It worked. I had to fix the func (please accept edit). Thank you.